# How to stop the recursive execution after some time in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, timeout

Currently We are triggering rate-limiting functionality, each time when user hits the service, code will check for the count in redis, if submission count is within the configured limit, we increment the count and allow the user to perform the operation otherwise we will recursively check for the limit for every 1 sec until validation succeeds.

```
async function _rateLimit() {
    const key = als.get("instanceId");
    let islimitExceeded = await redisClient.checkSubmissionCount(key,
        constants.REQUEST_LIMIT); // REQUEST_LIMIT is the configured limit lets take as 10
    if (!islimitExceeded) {
        await redisClient.incrementSubmissionCount(key);// increment the count and allow the user to perform the operation
    }
    else {
            await util.promisify(setTimeout)(1000).then(_rateLimit);
        }
}
```

Now the requirement is to throw the error if the limit is still exceeded(islimitExceeded=true) even after 10 seconds recursive check.

Help on this scenario . Thanks.

Comment: E.g. pass a "stepCount" to `_rateLimit`, increment it on each recursive call and if that count is 10 then you have obviously waited ten times and need to abort

Comment: I would recommend you try using event emitter if you can send event from redis to node app. Just like messaging in sockets. This will help you in terms of performance.

Comment: Thanks @luk2302 , But here I need to throw error after some seconds(I took as 10sec but it may vary) and the recursive call currently it is every 1 second(It may vary), could you tell me based on this scenario ?

Comment: why you don't express rate limit (https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-rate-limit)
it is a good package to your solution , may this will help you